# How can I parse tags from a csv in PowerBI?

Tags: csv, tags, powerbi

I have a source .csv with survey feedback in long text (column A) and tags (column B) like this:

```
|          A                   |              B             |
|I love your widgets!          |positive, love, widgets     |
|piece o' junk                 |negative, Irish, junk       |
```

In my end report I want to be able to use the Slicer widget to filter columnar results by the Tags.

How would I query my data to achieve this in PowerBI?

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to clean up your input (either outside PowerBI, or in the Query Editor) to something like this:

```
Text;Tags
I love your widgets!;positive, love, widgets
piece o' junk;negative, Irish, junk
```

Then load it up as CSV. Take these steps to chop them up:

1. Go to the Query Editor
2. Click on the Tags column
3. In the Home ribbon, click Split Column > By Delimiter
4. Choose "Comma" separator and "At each occurrence" in the popup
5. Hit Okay

You now have this:

[image: split in three tags cols]

You can go one step further and do this:

1. Select the tags columns
2. Go to the "Transform" ribbon
3. Click "Unpivot Columns"

You now have this:

[image: unpivoted result]

Now if you apply all these changes, and go back to the report, you can easily insert a slicer and select "Value" column to slice on:

[image: slicer]

You haven't specified much else about your data or report requirements, so you might have to adjust, copy datasets, etc. But this should get you started.